# Proof by induction that Catalan number $C_n$ is less or equal to $n!$

Tags: induction, factorial, catalan-numbers

In positive integer range,

I want to prove that Catalan(n) is always the same or smaller than Factorial(n) by using mathematical induction.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: For example, when n=3, C(3)= C(0)*C(2) + C(1)*C(1)+C(2)*C(0) so I thought about the relationship between C(3) and 3! and when number was n.but I couldn't think of it

Comment: Please don't vandalize your question after receiving answers.

Answer (score 2):

Hint (using your comment above): Note that $3!=3\cdot 2!=2!+2!+2!$. This can be compared directly, term-for-term, with your expression for $C(3)$ (using that $C(2)\leq 2!$, $C(1)\leq 1!$ and $C(0)\leq 0!$).

If you use (strong) induction, set up a similar relation for general $n$, and compare term-by-term, you can conclude.

Comment: thank you a lot..!!!! I'll try it

Answer (score 0):

This holds for $0 \leq n \leq 2$. Catalan(n) is $\frac{1}{n+1}{{2n} \choose n}$. It follows that the ratio of Catalan(n+1) to Catalan(n) is $\frac{4n+2}{n+2}$. We have $\frac{4n+2}{n+2} < n +1$ implies $n > 1$, and the result follows.